# jQuery how to add handler to new appeared elements

Tags: jquery

```
$(function(){

$('#somelement').click(function(){


  //do stuff

});


});
```

This code don't work on elements that have appeared a bit later, how to make this bind to all elements that will appear in the future

Comment: Event delegation... or bind the handlers to them when you add them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Direct vs. Delegated - jQuery .on()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on)

Answer (score 3):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

As your content is added dynamically so it is not accessible directly ,So you have to use Event delegation.

```
$(document).on('click','#somelement',function(){

});
```

or

you can bind the Event delegation to the parent element of the new element which is present in DOM at the of time DOM ready or page load.

```
$('#parentID').on('click','#somelement',function(){

});
```

Comment: @PSL yeah i am improving my post.